# How to query a DHCP server to get the local DNS servers

Tags: linux, dns, dhcp, centos-5

I have a ClarkConnect (CentOS based) box running as my home router on a RR connection.  I had the DNS servers set up to use Google's DNS server.  I want to change them back to the local DNS servers but I can't find an obvious/easy way to get those address short of a) reconfiguring the router's network to DHCP them (would rather not interrupt everyone) or b) calling their tech support (kill me now!).

Is there a command line tool/command I can use to query the DHCP server on the external NIC to see what DNS servers it would set me up with w/o munging my existing setup?

Answer (score 1):

If the question you really want to answer is "what are roadrunner's DNS servers?", Google finds [RoadRunner docs on this](http://www.roadrunnerguide.com/dns.html) (not responding currently -- [cached version](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:a5As4bEFCPQJ:www.roadrunnerguide.com/dns.html+roadrunner+dns+servers&hl=en&gl=us&strip=1)) with a big list of DNS servers in various areas of the country.

If you really do want to find out how to query the DHCP server, then this won't help.

---

*aside:* How would changing the DNS servers interrupt people on your network? If they got DNS servers from your router when their machines made DHCP requests locally, then they'll keep the Google DNS servers locally until their lease expires. New machines which connect to your router will get the local ISP DNS servers.

Comment: The +1 is for your aside.

Answer (score 0):

#### You don't. The DHCP server will tell you.

At least, if it's properly configured to send the `domain-name-servers` option parameter with the rest of the details when it hands out your IP address and network settings.

That option is a standard part of the DHCP protocol, and every existing server and client implentation *should* honor it if it's configured properly.